# Disabling bundled assets for a single request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

For `rack-mini-profiler` I would like to add a special diagnostic option that allows you to see your "expanded" css and js assets, in production.

So, if a user types in `http://somesite.com/?pp=expand_assets` we would inform sprockets somehow to fall back to serving the unminified and unbundled assets for this particular request. The rest of the requests should be unaffected.

How would I get something like this going? Do I need to monkey patch, or are there built in hooks?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Sprockets code, it looks like the [Rails helpers](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/lib/sprockets/rails/helpers/rails_helper.rb#L84) have this built in:

1. Enable fallback asset compiling by setting `config.assets.compile = true` in your environment's config file.
2. Add the param `debug_assets=true` to any request.

Comment: unfortunately once this is enabled, it enables it for all users, so it is a bit risky for production